# Logitech mouse m705 misses scrolls

Tags: scrolling, logitech-mouse, logitech-unifying-receiver

I've found a very annoying bug with my Logitech Marathon m705 mouse: sometimes ( like 1-2 of 10 ) it misses wheel scrolls. That doesn't depend on whether I use hyperscroll mode or not.
Neither it depends on scrolling direction. It is more likely to happen when mouse is on the move.

I've been using this mouse for 5 months and everything was fine. Yesterday I switched to another PC and now experiencing this problem. The main difference between PCs is that now I'm using 64bit version of Windows 7.

I don't know if this is important: I also use Logitech K350 keyboard with the same Unifying receiver.

Comment: I also have a M705 (actually I have 3). If it only started to happen with the new computer, then it is most likely due to that and not a problem those source is in the mouse itself. Unlike the issue I had with mine where the left mouse button wore out.

Comment: I've tried another mouse today. I've found that it doesn't depend on mouse, so with another one it also misses scrolls. So you are right that it is problem of the new PC, but I have no idea how to fix it :(

Answer (score 2):

Without the Setpoint I had absolutely no problem with scrolling(running Win7 x64), scroll missing begun with the installation of this software. Have K350 too, but I had this problem before I bought this keyboard.

So try to remove the SetPoint software and see if that helps.

Comment: Depending on the logitech device and it's current firmware, I had cases where installing setpoint improved the experience, and other cases where removing setpoint improved the experience. There's also something called Flow Scroll which I recommend to remove.